# KVM and restoring VM without the XML files

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

I have recently experienced a server outage that was hosting a couple VM's.  This server is irreparable. I have since installed a new server with Centos 7 and installed KVM.  I was able to connect and get access to the storage (ISCSI) where the VM's are stored.

Will I be able to get those VM's running again without the need to get the XML file that I have been reading so much about?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To clarify, The VM's are stored on another server via ISCSI.  I just need to be able to attach those VM's to the newly built host server that are located in /vms/iscsi directory.

I apologize if this isn’t clear enough, I’m not sure how to get any clearer.

thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create new VMs and add the .qcow2 harddisks available on iSCSI target in VMs.  In this way the machine will not be available in original state and you will need to reconfigure the CPU, Memory but all the data along with OS will remain intact which was part of the VM on now malfunctioning machine.  The xml files only contain the machine specific configuration parameters.